# Only Administrator can use Windows Explorer. Normal users get an error when accessing Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-explorer

If I log in as a standard user in my BRAND NEW Windows 7 install, I have no access to Windows Explorer. If I click on **Computer** in the Start Menu or the **Windows Explorer** folder icon in the taskbar I get the following error in a dialog box titled *Explorer.exe*:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

I have one Administrator account, which works fine, and four other standard accounts. I have this problem with ALL of the accounts except for the admin account.

Any idea what the heck is going on here???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so making new user accounts worked perfectly.
Advice for anyone performing a clean install of Windows: let windows download all automatic updates before creating any user accounts.

Comment: Interesting. Did you possibly add the accounts during the installation of said updates?

Comment: Sorry for such a late response. At this point in time I'm not quite sure because its been too long. I guess that may have been the issue. I made the accounts as soon as was possible I would imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Type the following in an elevated command prompt window:

`sfc /scannow`

This will check that all of your system files are in fact ok.

I would also run `chkdsk /f` to make sure your file system isn't corrupt for some or other reason.

---

Scan for malware too. It's possible, even on a fresh install, to have been infected by a drive-by download. I use SuperAntiSpyware, MalwareBytes and ComboFix (which now supports 64-bit, incidentally).

Comment: Wierd, as this is a brand new install, but I'll try it and see what happens...

Comment: Also, i've noticed that only 3 out of 4 standard account on the system have this problem...

Comment: I don't think the number of accounts is relevant, unless one  of them picked up malware, in which case you should scan for an infection as well.

Comment: Is it possible to pick up malware solely from downloading Chrome and System updates?

Comment: SFC didn't find anything. I'm just going to create new accounts and delete the old ones I guess and that'll probably solve everything.

Comment: Have you done the checkdisk and malware scan?

Comment: no, that would take too much time. I'm making new accounts as we speak to see what happens. I've never use malware apps ever. I actually dislike malware apps. I have a record of not getting any infections, especially with my closed network settings. 

I firmly believe it is some type of bug with Windows 7 that I happened to encounter after a series of unlucky and unfortunate events that most people rarely experience.

Comment: Ok, well apparently making new user accounts worked perfectly.